# jenkins pipeline echo multi line or hide the echo command

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, echo

I'm working on a jenkins pipeline, having to execute an URL, which returns log information in JSON.

We can get the correct info from this JSON, but on echo the output, it will all be on one line, where `\n`, `\r` will not output the text to a new line.

```
First line\nSecond line\rExtra line
```

Because it's more beautyful to have this log on multiple lines, I edited the JSON, so it will return the log as an array, to loop this

```
url_json["error"].each { item ->
    echo "${item}"
}
```

The output of this in the console log, will show:

```
[Pipeline] echo
First line
[Pipeline] echo
Second line
[Pipeline] echo
Extra line
```

This time, the output is on multiple lines, but the `[Pipeline] echo` make the output a bit harder to read, because I'm trying to get it like this in the console output:

```
First line
Second line
Extra line
```

I'm wondering for 2 things:

- is it possible to have an enter provided when doing `echo` in the console log?
- is it possible to get rid of that `[Pipeline] echo` line ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can prettify the entire JSON like below if that's your requirement.

```
def data = readJSON file: 'package.json'
def formtted = groovy.json.JsonOutput.prettyPrint(groovy.json.JsonOutput.toJson(data))
echo "$formtted"
```